# What’s the difference between chat_member and chat_participant in telegram?

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

I have telegram bot on `Node.js` with [telegraf](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf). When someone joins my `Telegram supergroup` I get the following `msg object` with these props:

```
msg.update.message: {
   from: {...}
   chat: { 
        id: -1891113454123,
        title: 'Title Group',
        type: 'supergroup' 
     },
     date: 1570365406,
     new_chat_participant: { 
        id: 746732141,
        is_bot: true,
        first_name: 'someBot',
        username: 'someBot' 
     },
     new_chat_member: { 
        id: 746732141,
        is_bot: true,
        first_name: 'someBot',
        username: 'someBot' 
     },

}
msg.updateSubTypes: [ 'new_chat_members' ],
```

I would like to do some business logic with new user's `id`, but 'Im not sure which one should I take for it: `new_chat_participant.id` or `new_chat_member.id`? What’s the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `new_chat_member`. They have renamed the field in [April 2016](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api-changelog#april-9-2016). So I would use the new name.

I guess they kept the old one for backward compatibility for now.

Comment: thx, surprised that I'm 1st who ask about it since 2016 on SO :D